# Given a vector field (dx, dy), move matrix value at position (Row, Col) to new position (Row + dx, Column + dy)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, image-processing

Given a matrix

```
[   a   b   -  ]
[   -   e   f  ]
[   g   h   -  ]
```

where, for the sake of demonstration, - denotes a zero entry.

We also work with a vector field

```
[   (0,1)   (0,1)   (0,0)  ]
[   (0,0)  (0,-1)  (0,-1)  ]
[   (0,1)   (0,1)   (0,0)  ]
```

where each tuple specifies how many (rows, columns) to move the corresponding element in the matrix. What is a Pythonic/efficient way to move each element by its corresponding vector to achieve:

```
[   -   a   b  ]
[   e   f   -  ]
[   -   g   h  ]
```

This was inspired by a coregistration problem, but I haven't found an elegant solution to this problem besides looping through element wise. I'm new to image processing, and also programming in Python - what is an efficient/accepted way to do this?

Comment: could you explain further on the logic transforming `a b c` to `c a b` using those tuples?

Comment: @AndyL. Sure. More explicitly, the vector field I'm working with is a deformation map. A toy example is an image of a face not smiling, and an image of the same face, smiling. All things considered, pixels of the lips move the most. Given a deformation map, how do I best approximate the smiling face from the non-smiling face using the deformation map?

Comment: is it a dataframe or numpy matrix?

Comment: @ansev I'm working with numpy, but I hope this question is broad enough to be generalized to other problems!

Comment: Can the values in a row of the vector field be different? For example: [   (0,1)   (1,1)   (0,1)  ]?

Comment: see `np.roll`...

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes! This suggests that multiple positions from the input can be moved to the same position of the output. Though I'm not sure, I think the value of this entry can be determined by it's absolute magnitude. In an image, I would retain the value with the highest intensity.

Comment: at `row 0`, could you explain how `a` moves to postion (0, 1) and `c` moves to position (0, 0) ?

Comment: @AndyL. This is a great question, thank you! I reformulated my problem to be more clear. I realize this is likely why others suggested ```np.roll```

Comment: Now it's even more confusing to me, as the positions would overlap after moving along the vector field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `np.add.at`:

```
A = np.array([["a","b",""],["","c","d"],["e","f",""]])
l,n,r = [[0,-1],[0,0],[0,1]]
B = np.array([[r,r,n],[n,l,l],[r,r,n]])

out = np.zeros_like(A)
i,j = np.ogrid[:3,:3]
np.add.at(out.view('u4'),(i+B[...,0],j+B[...,1]),A.view('u4'))

out
# array([['', 'a', 'b'],
#        ['c', 'd', ''],
#        ['', 'e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: I see. Why is it important to construct a view of my matrix w/ a different data-type (out.view('u4'))?

Comment: @batlike because numpy doesn't like adding strings. I assume in your real problem you will have a numeric dtype, so you needn't (actually, shouldn't) view cast..